# How to display string art patterns side by side in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, ascii

I am trying to display two string art patterns side by side in C#.

Maybe there exist a way that u can do this by ***ASCII*** code , but how that works e

I know some ways to do it and i've tried all but it **overlap** each other, bcs string structure its irregular, this is a "**flower**" that I have :

```
..O..
O.o.O
..O..
```

I have tried the `Console.WriteLine()` method , it prints it down in one column.

And others, look at my code:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.ASCII; //maybe this can be done in ASCII too.
    int r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // the flowers row
    int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //the flowers col
    string flower = @"..O..
                      O.o.O
                      ..O..";

    string s1 = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(flower + "\n", r)); //i multiply this string with the coefficent "r"

    string final = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(s1, c)); //i tried to concat the first one with that got generated and in this way i wanted to get flower in col and rows , like matrixes u know

    string s2 = string.Concat(s1); //tried to concat them , this works for simple strings but not for my kind of string
```

i want to get sth like this , 
*r = 2 , c = 5*
 the print would be :

```
..O....O....O....O....O..
O.o.OO.o.OO.o.OO.o.OO.o.O
..O....O....O....O....O..
..O....O....O....O....O..
O.o.OO.o.OO.o.OO.o.OO.o.O
..O....O....O....O....O..
```

But instead with those methods up it overlaps ore just print them in one col and 'r' rows, I'm having problems with the column part, to display them side by side.

Can anyone help me?

I would appreciate it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By splitting the pattern using`Environment.NewLine`, something like this might be generic enough to be re-used:

```cs
public static string RepeatPattern(string pattern, int rows, int columns)
{
    var patternSplitByLine = pattern.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    var oneColumnOutput = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0, j = patternSplitByLine.Length; i<j; i++)
        oneColumnOutput.Add(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(patternSplitByLine[i], columns)));

    var patternOneRowJoined = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, oneColumnOutput);
    var allRows = Enumerable.Repeat(patternOneRowJoined, rows);

    return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, allRows);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Wow, this is some pretty low level stuff.  Don't see this very often.

Here is what I would suggest.

1. Define a two-dimensional array of `char` sized appropriately for your display device (probably 80 columns x 43 rows, if I recall correctly)
2. Instead of printing your flowers, draw them in the array
3. When all of your flowers are done, convert the arrays to strings and output those.

Comment: this may be a good idea , i will try it! Thank for your answer